# How to sortables Draggables 2 head

Tags: javascript, php

My code:

```
<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
      revert: true
    });

    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({
      connectToSortable: "#sortable",
      helper: "clone",
      revert: "invalid"
    });

    $( "ul, li" ).disableSelection();
  } );
</script>

<?php 
  $heads = array("test", "test2");
  $num = count($heads);
  $data = array("1", "2", "3","4","5");
  $num2 = count($data);
?>


<ul>
  <?php 
    for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++){ 
  ?>
  <li id="draggable" class="ui-state-highlight"><?php echo $heads[$i] ?>
  </li>

    <?php } ?>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable">


<?php
for($i=0;$i<$num2;$i++){ 
?>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><?php echo $data[$i] ?></li>
    <?php } ?>

 </ul>
```

How to Make it available.

I'm starting to learn JS. I still can not understand JS much, but I need to use this Draggable.

I would like to have two Draggable head and can use both, but now it is not available. I want to retrieve array data into the Draggable head.

Comment: Erm, come again?

Comment: PHP runs server side, JS runs client side. `Draggable` is not a function ive heard of, might be jQuery, in either event PHP is irrelevant, show the generated code and your attempt to interact with it.